# AJAX search - parsing and reading the URL parameters with hash tags

Tags: ajax

we've implemented a new AJAX based search on our website. We're adding the parameters and their values with # tag at the end of the main URL, when user makes further refine by applying additional filters.

This was done to enable our users to share the URL of what they were viewing. It's actually now achieved in a way that the page gets redirected and the content is generated first for the base URL. Using a Javascript function which executes onload looks at the parameters in the # tags and makes another AJAX hit.

**Questions:**

1. Why browsers are not sending the # thing to the server. i.e.; # part is not even received by the HTTP Server. It's interesting actually, browsers are not sending them at all
2. What is best way to get the # values? I'm looking at more of to avoid the double hit that we've implemented right now. i.e.; content is loaded already and then making another AJAX call to apply the refines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#` value is an instruction to the browser to look for a named anchor in the document it is to load from the server. It is interpreted and actioned by the browser. The server can do nothing with it, so there's no point in sending it. If you're trying to use this for some other purpose then you'll run into difficulties - as you have found.

There is a mechanism for sending data to the server: the querystring. Append your parameters to the URL prefixed by a `?`, in the form `variablename=data`, with successive variables separated by a `&`.